# Trouble with printing C++ Hash Table

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to C++ and am trying to teach myself how to implement a hash table(I know I could use unordered_map, but I'm challenging myself). Right now I have a vector of structs(cell) that holds person-specific information. I have a PrintTable function that I want to use to print out each struct member of every item in the table. However, I can't seem to access the specific members of the struct(cell). What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct cell
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
    std::string weapon;
};

class HashTable
{
private:
    std::vector<cell> *table;
    int total_elements;

    int getHash(int key)
    {
        return key % total_elements;
    }

public:
    HashTable(int n)
    {
        total_elements = n;
        table = new std::vector<cell>[total_elements];
    }

    void SearchTheTable(int hashIndex);
    void AddItem(std::string name, int age, std::string weapon);
    void RemoveItem();
    void PrintTable();
};

void HashTable::SearchTheTable(int hashIndex)
{
    int x = getHash(hashIndex);
    std::cout << x;
}

void HashTable::AddItem(std::string name, int age, std::string weapon)
{
    cell newCell = { name, age, weapon };
    table->push_back(newCell);
}

void HashTable::RemoveItem()
{

}

void HashTable::PrintTable()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < table->size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << table[i].name; // Right here I get an error that says: class "std::vector<cell, std::allocator<cell>>" has no member "name".
    }
}

int main()
{
    HashTable theTable(5);
    theTable.AddItem("Ryan", 27, "Sword");
    theTable.AddItem("Melony", 24, "Axe");
    theTable.PrintTable();
}
```

Comment: If you're learning C++ that's great, but this is also the perfect opportunity to learn about *templates* so this table isn't `cell` specific.

Comment: It's not necessary nor advised to have your `std::vector<cell>` as a pointer. You can always initialize a property however you like using a [constructor list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor). It's also doubly bizarre to use both `std::vector` and `new[]` together. This should be `std::vector<std::vector<cell>>` and you can eliminate all the manual allocations. It's worth noting this structure is incomplete: **If you allocate memory you must eventually release it** as in you need a destructor.

Comment: Do you want a single-level hash table where there's one element per index, or is this a chain approach where more than one can occupy an index? Both have their place, but you seem to be using a bit from each approach, where these approaches have a very different internal structure.

Comment: Chaining is used to avoid collision, right? I'm not worried about that right now so I guess just single-level works for me. Also, I will definitely research templates and memory allocation now, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Two strategies work: When a collision occurs you increase the size of the table and rehash the existing content to spread it out, or when a collision occurs you just chain it on to an array/linked list at that slot. You need to pick one. If you're doing a single level, then `std::vector<cell>` is fine, no pointer, no inner structure. If you collide, you resize and rebuild the table.

Comment: It's worth noting that picking a proper size and size scaling function is critical here. Sizes are best when prime numbers, worst when powers of two.